# Lost Chrome Tabs, Did Something Really Dumb- Situation Still Salvageable?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

Alright, I'm sure this situation has came up before here, but in my case, I did something truly boneheaded that probably most others had not done before.  Long story short:

- Had over 200 tabs on a Chrome window I had meticulously saved up, but didn't know how it really operated
- Decided to reactivate my Battle.net account (wanted to replay Starcraft 2) while I was out of Chrome.

-Payment screen prompted Chrome to open(???), and voila, **a completely new session arose,** **wiping off all of my saved tabs**.

-Didn't know what was going on, in fit of panic **closed that window and opened a new one (D'oh!)**

-Tried opening new windows, but you can guess the result.  Nothing there, old tabs still gone

- Tried to restore Chrome to an earlier version, too bad my system didn't have a save point BEFORE the wipeout.

So I'm totally stuck here.  Is there any conceivable way at all for me to recover that long lost session with all my 200+ tabs?

Thank you!

  -

Comment: Just a tip for the future: I had this exact problem - use [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en).

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/613687/made-a-stupid-mistake-with-google-chrome-tabs-situation-still-salvageable by same user.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need to find the Last Session and Last Tabs files located:

On a Mac:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/
```

On Windows:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

I'm on OSX so I haven't validated this info.

Windows path from http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UPbxgK8jSR4

Once you locate Last Session and Last Tabs, copy them into the Chrome folder as Current Session and Current Tabs, respectively. Good luck!

Comment: I tried that but the same story pops up: it just goes to the most recent one with only a few tabs, not the old one with 200+ in them.

Comment: Did you open another session in between? Sadly I'm not sure how much more info is stored. There might be some log files that you could comb to find the most important tabs, but I'm not sure if logging is enabled by default/how much info would actually be there.

Comment: This doesn't work. Any way to go back in history? Presumably Google stores all of this.

Answer (score -3):

You would need to do this while the session that you started in  which the tabs first disappeared is still open.  Copy the two files to another location, such as the desktop.  Then close Chrome, rename the files, copy them back and replace.  If this does not work, use Recuva (a program) to find the files that have been deleted.  However, this may be hard, because Recuva works best with files that are normally deleted (from the Recycle Bin), rather then overwritten as these files are.  If none of these things works, then you cannot get your tqabs back except by going to history.

However, Chrome does write all tabs into the history, even if you do what I do and disable DHCP client while the tabs are loading so that your computer does not slow down form he amount of open tabs (this turns the Internet off).  So, if you have opened the browser and then closed it shortly afterwards without looking at too many new pages, the open tabs will be the last 200 on the list after you skip past the few you did open...   to be safe, if you knew ou had exactly 200, I'd open 250.  It's annoying as fuck if you have to do it all by hand but at least you'll eventually get your tabs back.  Assuming of course that your last session did not involve too many new pages.

Comment: _"Chrome does write all tabs into the history, even if you do what I do and disable DHCP client while the tabs are loading so that your computer does not slow down form he amount of open tabs (this turns the Internet off)"_ This is pure art.